# Trying to fetch all rows filtered by id and returning them as array(mysql,php)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm sending username to database as a filter to get only rows of data that are associated with it using Ajax but I'm getting empty response back.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'fetch_followed_users.php',
        data: {
            user : username, 
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(follows) {



                 var jArrayAllFollows=[];
                 jArrayAllFollows = follows;

        },
 });
```

And this is from fetch_followed_users.php:

```
<?php

   session_start();

   require 'database.php';

      $sql6 =  $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM followedusers WHERE user = :user"); 
      $sql6->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']); 
      $sql6->execute();
      $results=array();
      $results = $sql6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)

      echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

I'd appreciate any help. I know this is a simple thing to do, but I just can't get it right.

Comment: can you show ajax request response?

Comment: you already have the whole data inside `follows`, why would you need another loop inside the success block, and if you're just concerned about the count, why not just have a server response to return the actual count, `echo json_encode(array('count' => count in php))`, then just read `follows.count` and thats it

Comment: Are you getting anything in response ? if not then change remove datatype tag in ajax call

Comment: btw, isn't this `mysqli`? i don't think named placeholders are allowed in prepared statements, or is this `PDO`, this is kinda mixed up

Comment: I'm not getting any response back. Ajax is correctly sending username as user to fetch_followed_users. I tried removing datatype. And Ghost, I haven't made any courses on mysqli or PDO, I'm fixing that as we speak so that's why it's all a mess because I've been trying to use examples from here and make it work. It's kind of mix and mash from my old code and new from an example here. I guess the old needs replacing here then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it simpler, just get the count in PHP and send that as a response.

Basic idea:

In PHP get the value and send the count:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'database.php';

$sql6 =  $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM followedusers WHERE user = :user"); 
$sql6->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']); 
$sql6->execute();
$count = $sql6->fetchColumn();

echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));

?>
```

Then in JS success block, just access the response:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.count);
    // do what you will with the count
},
```

Note: Don't mix MySQLi with PDO, just pick one and use it all through out your code.

Comment: { $sql6 =  $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM followedusers WHERE user = :user"); 
$sql6->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']); 
$sql6->execute();
$results=array();
$results = $sql6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)

echo json_encode($results);

Comment: @Still.Learning that is an incorrect PDO flag to use, use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: @Still.Learning sure glad this helped